# How can i get this kind of window?

Tags: java

In eclipse you can detach tabs and they will displayed in a special kind of window.

Win7 with aero displays it as follows

http://www.oliholz.de/data/1.jpg

How can i produce this frame?  i have tried many styles of JFrame,JWindow,JDialog, ...

Comment: Eclipse uses it's own library for UI, not swing. Check the eclipse page for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other people mentioned eclipse uses it's own library for UI. That library is based on SWT which is better integrated with the native window system. 
See [this article](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/10936_2179061_1/Swing-and-SWT-A-Tale-of-Two-Java-GUI-Libraries.htm) for explanation on how SWT, AWT, and Swing relate to each other.
Eclipse Rich Client Platform which is also mentioned here can be observed as a layer above SWT that can make your life much easier if you intend to develop a complex, feature rich application (for example an IDE for the new programming language you made).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Eclipse Rich Client Platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform). If you want to emulate their look and feel, you might consider building your user interface upon their free (and rather good) open source framework.